# Create or update record in ActiveAndroid ORM

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, activeandroid

I'm using active android as orm in my android project.
after I get a json response from server, I wanna create a field if that item does not exist, or update it if that item already exists.
Record existence is determined via a field named `slug`.
How can I achieve this via ActiveAndroid? since I don't see how to achieve in the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your class name is `YOUR_CLASS` which has a `slug` field. Then do the following with `ActiveAndroid`:

```
YOUR_CLASS item = new Select()
                        .from(YOUR_CLASS.class)
                        .where(slug = ?,_slug_value_)
                        .executeSingle();
if(item == null) {
    item = new YOUR_CLASS();
    item.slug = _slug_value_;
} 
//change what you want then save the item.
item._field_to_change_ = _new_value_;
item.save();
```